# IndexError: list index out of range when removing duplicates

Tags: python, duplicates

This code works

```
  X = ['jennifer', 1, 1, 2, 'apple', 3, 3, 1, 'apple', ['true', 'burps','taste',   'good'], ['true', 'burps', 'taste', 'good'], 3, 'jennifer'] 

for index in reversed(range(len(X))):
  if X.count(X[index]) > 1:
      X.remove(X[index])
```

giving me a list with no duplicates

```
[2, 1, 'apple', ['true', 'burps', 'taste', 'good'], 3, 'jennifer']
```

I just don't understand why this only works when going in reverse. Why isn't the following the exact same thing?

```
for i in range(0,len(X)):
    if X.count(X[i]) > 1:
        X.remove(X[i])
```

I get an error

```
 if X.count(X[i]) > 1:
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Either way I am removing an element from a list I am reading, so why would the first example not go out of range but the second one would? Can I do something to the second example to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your second example will not work. The reason why the reversed version works, is that at the worst case you are only accessing the "LAST" element of the list.

So suppose `X` have 5 elements and all are duplicates, so you are removing all elements until there is one left. At first, `len(X)` is 5, so your for-loop will loop for `4 3 2 1 0`. Everytime you remove 1 element, the list shrinks by 1. So the maximum index that you can access, starts from `4`, then shrinks to `3`, `2`, `1`, `0`, which is exactly the sequence you are accessing the list, therefore you won't have the IndexError.

A table of the values of index, and the maximum index accessible from X in each step:

```
index  Max. index of X
4      4
3      3
2      2
1      1
0      0
```

If you try to remove more than 1 elements(eg. all duplicates in 1 step) each round, you may see the IndexError again.

Answer (score 3):

You're modifying the list while iterating, so every time you delete something going forward you reduce its `len`, and towards the end of your iteration your indices will be out of range. By going backwards, you don't run into that problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to change a list while iterating through it as in:

```
for i in range(0,len(X)):
if X.count(X[i]) > 1:
    X.remove(X[i])
```

One option is create a list with the ones you want to remove and then iterate again copying who is not in this list.

Another option is to use the `set object`, that does not allow duplicates.

Comment: That is probably true but I am working with the idea of lists being mutable and I feel certain it can be done this way- I am just missing how.

Comment: The best option then is to iterate backwards as the other anwser says. But you can still use the set object, that does not allow duplicates.